# TSQL: View Performance Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Problem with the following Query. It works and gives me the needed result, BUT it is quite slow, because of my subselects with joins. My TSQL skills are not good enough to optimize this Query. Maybe some of you can help.

```
SELECT
    Id AS InstanceId,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE  (tpr.ProcessResultId = 32)) AS Received,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE        (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 1)) AS Queued,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE  (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 2)) AS Processed,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE  (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 128)) AS Error,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE  (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 256)) AS Rejected,
    (SELECT COUNT(tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE  (tpr.ProcessResultId = 16)) AS Duplicates,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
     FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     WHERE  (tpr.ProcessResultId = 2)) AS Nack 
FROM
    dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic 
WHERE
    (InstanceGroupId = 1)
```

This Query runs as a View.

If you Need further Information, let me know.

Here are the table Informations

tProcessLog

```
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[InstanceConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
[InputQueueEntryId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[OutputQueueEntryId] [bigint] NULL,
[ProcessingDtm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ProcessResultId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SeverityId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LogText] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[IsHidden] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ReceiverId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

tInputQueueEntry

```
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DataTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CodePage] [int] NOT NULL,
[InMsgStateFlags] [int] NOT NULL,
[ContentData] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ContentHash] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
```

tInstanceConfig

```
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ComponentConfig] [xml] NOT NULL,
[InstanceGroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, i think there is no way to get much more Performance. I used the MSSQL Tuning Advisor which had some recommendations, now the query tooks ~500ms. That is okay for me.

Thanks to all answers ! I doesnt help the Performance issue, but i learned cool new tsql stuff :)

Comment: I think you can use one `JOIN` instead of all inner-selects with use `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN <someConditions> THEN tiq.Id END)` ;).

Comment: i believe that only 1 return value is accepted in a subselect :(

Comment: Could you add what execution plans this produces? And what are indexes on your table? It would be helpful.

Comment: the execution plan has 2k + lines ... how should i add the XML ?

Comment: What happens if you remove all DISTINCT? (not the correct result of course but is there a big difference in speed?)

Comment: @adrianm ... it takes half the time now ... 800ms without <> 1,7s with

Comment: You should rewrite this query using joins. If this is not possible, run this query in SSMS and view "actual execution plan". It might suggest some indexes that you can use to optimize query.

Comment: @SalmanA there was 1 missing index suggested, i already added ... but it had no effect

Comment: the Database Tuning advisor has some recommendations ... i will try them

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
SELECT
    tic.Id AS InstanceId,
    count.*
FROM
    dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic 
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tpr.ProcessResultId = 32 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Received,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 1 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Queued,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 2 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Processed,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 128 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Error,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 256 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Rejected,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tpr.ProcessResultId = 16 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Duplicates,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tpr.ProcessResultId = 2 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Nack
        FROM   
            dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq 
            INNER JOIN dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id AND tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
    ) count
WHERE
    (InstanceGroupId = 1)
```

Comment: I will try, give me a second

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: There's a typo in the code. `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tpr.ProcessResultId = 2 THEN tiq.Id END) AS Nack,` last comma is redundant.

Comment: Now it works, but it is 2 times slower than my initial query :) 2 seconds

Comment: @S.L. Oh, may be the `tProcessLog` table is too big to run those 7 duplicate `Count()` for null entries

Comment: @Eric this table has 300k entries in my test DB

Comment: @Eric .. 2 times slower was wrong ... just 300-400ms

Comment: You can perform parallel execution by declaring variable as my below code.

Answer (score 2):

```html
DECLARE @Received INT,@Queued INT,@Processed INT,@Error INT,@Rejected INT,@Duplicates INT,@Nack INT

SET @Received =  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
         FROM   
            dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq 
         INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
         INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id
         WHERE  (tpr.ProcessResultId = 32)

SET @Queued =  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
         FROM   
            dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq 
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
         INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id
         WHERE        (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 1) 

SET @Processed =  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
                 FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
                        dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
                        INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id
                 WHERE  (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 2)   

SET @Error   = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
                 FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
                        dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
                        INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id 
                 WHERE  (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 128)

SET @Rejected = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
             FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
                    dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id
             WHERE  (tiq.InMsgStateFlags = 256) 

SET @Duplicates = SELECT COUNT(tiq.Id) AS Expr1
                 FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
                        dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
                        INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id
                 WHERE  (tpr.ProcessResultId = 16)  
SET @Nack = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tiq.Id) AS Expr1
    FROM   dbo.tInputQueueEntry AS tiq INNER JOIN
     dbo.tProcessLog AS tpr ON tpr.InputQueueEntryId = tiq.Id
     INNER JOIN dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic ON tpr.InstanceConfigId = tic.Id
    WHERE  (tpr.ProcessResultId = 2)                 

SELECT
    Id AS InstanceId,
    @Received AS Received,
    @Queued AS Queued,
    @Processed AS Processed,
    @Error AS Error,
    @Rejected AS Rejected,
    @Duplicates AS Duplicates,
    @Nack AS Nack 
FROM
    dbo.tInstanceConfig AS tic 
WHERE
    (InstanceGroupId = 1)
```

Comment: thanks ! but i cannot execute this query. there are several Syntax errors

Comment: you Need braces around each select ... but there is one error left .. he doesnt know "tic.Id" in each select

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 37
The multi-part identifier "tic.Id" could not be bound.

Comment: check now i have added one join condition

Comment: thanks for your Approach. Now it works but gives wrong results (each row has the same Counts) and it is as fast as my initial query with new indices ... ~500-600ms

Comment: Sorry i just forgot to add filter condition in all variable output, if you want this logic then can add : and   (InstanceGroupId = 1)  in each declare variable query.

Comment: this is nice and new for me, but there seems to be no Performance Advantage on my SQL Server. I give you +1 because i learned something

Answer (score 1):

Cant you `GROUP BY` using `InMsgStateFlags` and get the `count(1)` value since other conditions are same? Just write one `SELECT` statement.

Comment: do you have any example ? I have no idea what i have to do